# when i use g3d.the follewing error occur ''Invalid version line in #version 410".how to solve it?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I am g3d engine beginners.When I finished the tutorial in the set, I started running the start program(D:\g3d\G3D10\samples\starter), but the following problems, how can I solve?
**Invalid version line in "#version 410 // -*- c++ -*-"   Expression: false ..\GLG3D.lib\source\Shader_preprocessor.cpp:899**

[error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYce.png)

[G3D document](http://g3d.cs.williams.edu/g3d/G3D10/readme.md.html)

Comment: Does your GPU support GL 4.1? The support will depend on: 1) GPU model; 2) manufacturer drivers currently installed on your machine.

Comment: may be my gpu can't support GL4.1  [gpu-test1](http://gpuz.techpowerup.com/17/04/06/kjb.png)  [gpu-test2](http://gpuz.techpowerup.com/17/04/06/agq.png) .My computer has two graphics cards，the gpu-z prompt the second one can support opengl1.2  ,so Is there any way to run g3d?

Comment: The programmatic way to find supported version of OpenGL on your machine is to call [glGetString](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glGetString), with `GL_VERSION` as parameter.